# Equation to determine group from index

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

A simple thought experiment I devised and can't figure an equation to solve:

Lets say we have a series of groups starting at group $1$ up to some group $p$. Every odd digit group has exactly $1$ item and every even digit group has exactly $n$ items.

Let $G_{n,p}(i)$ determine the group that an item at index $i$ belongs to. For instance:

$$G_{2,6}(5)=4$$
[I][II][I][$\color{red}I$I][I][II]
$$G_{3,12}(19)=10$$
[I][III][I][III][I][III][I][III][I][I$\color{red}I$I][I][III]

I cannot find the function $G()$

Answer (score 1):

The presence of $p$ does not really affect the function except for making it undefined for $i>p(n+1)$. Let's forget $p$, i.e., consider the sequence as infinite. The number $$k=\left\lfloor \frac{i+1}{n+1}\right\rfloor $$
expresses how many pairs of 1-$n$ groups precede $i$. That is, $i$ belongs to the $(k+1)$th *pair*. Within this pair, we have two possibilities:

- $i+1=k(n+1) $. Then $i$ belongs to a group of 1 item, that is $G_n(i)=2k+1$.
- $i+1>k(n+1) $. Then $i$ belongs to a group of $n$ items, that is $G_n(i)=2k+2$.

In the presence of $p$, you just throw *undefined* if $i>p(n+1)$,   otherwise calculate as above.